# Как добавить значок с номером в иконку айтема BottomNavigation?

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-navigation-view

Ситуация такая. В Bottom Navigation нужно добавить иконку корзины. Но в зависимости от числа товаров в этой корзине - над этой иконкой должен появляться кружочек с числом эти товаров

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если корзина пуста, этот круг должен скрываться. Проблема в том, что я могу установить только 1 иконку. Пытался объединить эти 2 элемента в layout и показывать их, скрывая круг при необходимости. Но item в качестве иконки принимает только `drawable`, `minmap` и `color`

**Xml файл для меню**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/nav_bar_home_selection"
        android:title="Home"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/basket_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/nav_bar_basket_selection"
        android:title="Basket"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/favorite_fragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/nav_bar_favorite_selection"
        android:title="Favorite"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43194243/7540461

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете создать значок:

```
var badge = bottomNavigation.getOrCreateBadge(menuItemId)
badge.isVisible = true
// An icon only badge will be displayed unless a number is set:
badge.number = 99
```

Если вам нужно менять видимость значка, то сделать это можно так:

```
val badgeDrawable = bottomNavigation.getBadge(menuItemId)
    if (badgeDrawable != null) {
        badgeDrawable.isVisible = false
        badgeDrawable.clearNumber()
    }
```

Для удаления:

```
bottomNavigation.removeBadge(menuItemId)
```

[Здесь](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation) есть более подробное руководство.